# How to display menu bar over slideshow block?

Tags: views

On [my site](http://test7.muziclub.com/node/25), I am not able to show menu bar over the slider block in content. When I click the menu over the slide image, part of it disappear under the slide block.

When I click on the Services menu, it shows odd things. This problem is not persist on IE.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the [z-index](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) property of your menu bar.

If this does not help, add the `position:absolute` property in CSS class; and also add the `position:relative` property to the container of the menu bar class.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS style to your CSS file.

```css
    #views_slideshow_cycle_teaser_section_sunday_jam_image_slider-block {
       z-index: 0;
    }
```

Alternatively, try adding z-index to your dropdown class.

```css
/* Navigation Style */
.dropdown {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By simply giving a css property to the menu.

1. giving position as absolute
      position:absolute;
2. giving a positive z index
      z-index:100;